# Error in hadoop 2.6 streaming when processing large files only

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming

I am using Hadooop 2.6 streaming with python in a YARN env with 3 node cluster.

I can run a mapreduce successfully with a 1, 5, or 10 GB data file.
However, when I give the same mapreduce call a 15 or 24 GB data file it fails with the following error when it gets to the reduce stage:

```
15/08/16 18:58:55 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 69% reduce 20%
15/08/16 18:58:56 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1439307476930_0012_m_000094_2, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:322)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:535)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:61)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:34)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:450)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild$2.run(YarnChild.java:163)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1628)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnChild.main(YarnChild.java:158)
```

The stderr is seemingly not any more helpful:

```
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:44 PM com.google.inject.servlet.InternalServletModule$BackwardsCompatibleServletContextProvider get
WARNING: You are attempting to use a deprecated API (specifically, attempting to @Inject ServletContext inside an eagerly created singleton. While we allow this for backwards compatibility, be warned that this MAY have unexpected behavior if you have more than one injector (with ServletModule) running in the same JVM. Please consult the Guice documentation at http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets for more information.
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:45 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver as a provider class
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:45 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler as a provider class
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:45 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory register
INFO: Registering org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices as a root resource class
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:45 PM com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl _initiate
INFO: Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.9 09/02/2011 11:17 AM'
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:45 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.JAXBContextResolver to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:45 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.yarn.webapp.GenericExceptionHandler to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "Singleton"
Aug 16, 2015 6:56:46 PM com.sun.jersey.guice.spi.container.GuiceComponentProviderFactory getComponentProvider
INFO: Binding org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.webapp.AMWebServices to GuiceManagedComponentProvider with the scope "PerRequest"
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Here is my hadoop command:

```
hadoop jar $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/tools/lib/hadoop-streaming-2.6.0.jar \
-D stream.map.output.field.separator=, \
-D stream.num.map.output.key.fields=5 \
-D mapreduce.map.output.key.field.separator=, \
-D mapreduce.partition.keypartitioner.options=-k1,2 \
-D log4j.configuration=/usr/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/etc/hadoop/log4j.properties \
-file /usr/hadoop/code/sgw/mapper_sgw_lgi.py \
-mapper 'python mapper_sgw_lgi.py 172.27.64.10' \
-file /usr/hadoop/code/sgw/reducer_sgw_lgi.py \
-reducer 'python reducer_sgw_lgi.py' \
-partitioner org.apache.hadoop.mapred.lib.KeyFieldBasedPartitioner \
-input /input/172.27.64.10_sgw_1-150_06212015-nl.log \
-output output3
```

Comment: What does /usr/hadoop/code/sgw/mapper_sgw_lgi.py look like, specifically does it have a shebang line?

Comment: Yes it does: #!/usr/bin/env python

Comment: As I said above the mapper and reduce work fine with smaller files so there should not be any issues with the mapper or reducer code